# Multiple jquery-ui datepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

So here is my issue: I am building a form builder. This of course allows the user to "preview" his form as he builds it. Including adding datepickers (currently it just targets the div and activates it )

code:

```
$('#'+name).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "1900:2050"
});
```

The problem comes when I need to "rebuild" the form for editing. I want to provide the same functionality, basically they an see a live "working" version if you will. This works as you add it to the page, but rebinding can be an issue. See below.

I've tried a couple things:

-- Initialize at load on the class:

```
$(function(){    $('.class-name').datepicker(); });
```

This of course doesn't work when you later add a datepicker to the page.

I know what you are thinking, just initialize the ones that are there with the classs, then initialize them individually as they get added. Unfortunately they don't seem to work like that.

I tried, on initial load of the page initializing them. Then, if a new one is added, I did this:

```
$('.datepickers').each(function(i,el){
            $(el).datepicker( "destroy" );
            $(el).datepicker(); 
        });
```

to see if it would work. Nothing seems to give. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
When I add a new datepicker to my form, this is the HTML that is added

```
<div id="asdas-block" class="datepicker-wrapper form-input-wrapper">
        <div class="template-drag-handle"><img src="images/design/up-down-icon.png" class="template-drag-handle-icon" alt="Drag"></div>
        <div class="inputs-wrapper">
            <div class="form-row"><input type="text" name="asdas" class="input-datepicker hasDatepicker" placeholder="asdas" id="asdas"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="options-wrapper">
            <div class="required-chkbox options-chkbox-wrapper"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="asdas_required" id="asdas_required" {required}=""></div>
            <div class="public-chkbox options-chkbox-wrapper"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="asdas_public" id="asdas_public" {public}=""></div>
            <div class="searchable-chkbox options-chkbox-wrapper"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="asdas_searchable" id="asdas_searchable" {searchable}=""></div>
            <div class="searchable-chkbox options-chkbox-wrapper"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="asdas_searchable" id="asdas_published" {published}=""></div>
            <div class="delete-btn options-chkbox-wrapper"><a href="javascript:;" class="removeInput" data-remove-elm="asdas"><img src="/images/design/circle-close-icon.png" class="remove-field-icon" alt="Delete"></a></div>
        </div>  </div>
```

note: asdas was the "name" given to the example. When trying to do `$('#asdas').datepicker()` nothing happens.

Nothing happens if I try to do the entire `input-datepicker` class again either.

[image: Misc]

Photo just shows a working datepicker (using the classname method. And also that the new input seems to get the "hasDatepicker" class added even though it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: initializing the datepickers after adding them seems to work for me https://jsfiddle.net/masquino/0nq7gqf3/

Comment: "Dont seem to work like that" what doesn't work can you dump all this into a snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: Looking at the fiddle, I have no idea why this wont work. It's too much for a fiddle. Let me try something else.